# How can I calculate accuracy of an estimate based on a subset of data?

Tags: statistics, average, means

For example, say I'm trying to determine the average number of steps taken in a day for a population of 100M people. I know the exact number of steps for a random 25M subset of the 100M group (2500 per day).

How accurate is my 2500 steps per day number when applied to the whole 100M person group? Assume the Standard Deviation of the 25M sample is 20k.

Say I only had data for 100 or 1000 people of the 100M group. How does the accuracy change?

Comment: Often people refer to the [Standard Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) to describe the distribution of the sample mean for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks @lulu. Can you help me calculate the Standard Error in the above scenario then? The wiki article shows lots of equations. I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Can't write up anything now, sorry.  Roughly speaking, the standard deviation of the sample mean, given a sample of size $n$, is $\frac s{\sqrt n}$ where $s$ is the sample standard deviation.  You do need to know $s$, but surely your data lets you compute that.

Comment: Okay, the sample standard deviation is 20000 (some people take a TON of steps).

Comment: So 20000/√25000000 = 4.  Is 4 the Standard Error? Please help me write the final statement. Is it... Among this 100M person group, they take 2500 steps per day (+/-4 steps)? Or is it +/-4% (100 steps)?

Comment: The standard deviation is in the same units as your measurements.

Comment: What your calculation shows  is that the distribution of sample means will have standard deviation $4$.  That is very, very low which is consistent with your sample being enormous.  Still, to be precise:  all you have shown is that if you take a sample of that size then, say there is a $68\%$ chance that the sample mean will be within $4$ of the sample mean (and a $99.7\%$ chance that it will be within $12$, and so on).

Comment: How did you get 68%? and 99.7%?

Comment: That's the usual rule of thumb...in a normal distribution $68\%$ of the data lies within $1\;\sigma$ of the mean, $95\%$ within $2\;\sigma$, $99.7\%$ with $3 \; \sigma$.

Comment: With such a huge sample it's a bit of a quibble but:  keep in mind that the Standard Error concerns the sampling process, not any particular sample.  That is, the estimates I mentioned refer to the process by which a sample mean is extracted not to the result of one particular sample.  People get this confused all the time.  The analogy is:  rolling a fair die, you get $≤5$ with probability $.8\overline 3$. But if you roll the die and get a $6$ this does not mean that there is an $.8\overline 3$ probability that $6≤5$.

Comment: Thanks for your help @lulu. I think I'm getting it now. Is this how you would summarize this data? `The average steps per day is 2500 (99.7%, ±12 steps).`

Comment: Yes, that's not unfair.  For the huge sample of course.  For a smaller sample  the $99.7\%$ confidence interval will be considerably wider.

Comment: Right. So if my sample set was only 1000, but the standard deviation remained 20k, then...  20000/√1000 = 632. Therefore... `The average steps per day is 2500 (99.7%, ±1897 steps).` ... Or, if one would prefer, `The average steps per day is 2500 (95%, ±1265 steps).`  Is that how you would write the last bit — `2500 (95%, ±1265 steps)` — or is there a standard syntax for writing this? Also, please consider leaving an answer below so I can accept it. Thanks for all of your help.